# Can I share same Cell of UICollectionView with UITableView?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview, cell, swift5

I have created a cell.xib which is already subclass of UICollectionView already.

Later I decided to create a TableView in another ViewController... I wrote the code and everything except registering the cell I was unable to register the cell which is subclass of collectionView (which is registered already inside collectionView in other page) inside the TableView!

I got this warning or error

[image: Can I share same Cell of UICollectionView with UITableView?]

So, Please anyone can help me  and tell me how to do it in the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that FproductsCell is not a sublcass of UITableViewCell and thats why you get the error.

Create your UITableViewCell subclass in a xib and from this point, you have to register it to every UITableView where you want to use this cell in, programatically. Your class has to be inherited from UITableViewCell

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.register(YourCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "YourIdentifier")
}
```